# codeigniter jquery dynamic data

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In Codeigniter, I am loading a view through the controller and sending a data array like so

```
$results['data_array'] = $data_array;
$this->load->view('results', $results);
```

Is it possible to access this data array through a jQuery function and if so how?

Comment: You need to post html where you `echo` that data

Answer (score 3):

Inside `results` view you can do the following to get that array into a javascript variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataArr = <?php echo json_encode($data_array); ?>;
</script>
```

Then `dataArr` will contain the same array you passed from the controller. You can use it anywhere. Like to loop through it you can use `$.each` like

```
$.each(dataArr,function(index,val){
   // perform operation
});
```

Comment: _Answer corrected after this comment was posted._ As is, that will not work because you are not outputting a string into JS. There is no reason to run `.parseJSON` on the PHP outputted JSON encoded data. Remove the `.parseJSON` call, or output the data wrapped in quotes such that it is a string in the resulting JS (the latter would be kind of pointless).

Comment: Joy, no problem, glad it's fixed up. Will +1